# Ipython3, how do you remove the ...: symbol that indicates an indent?

Tags: python-3.x, format, ipython

I like to first code in the terminal and then copy over my function to my script if it works. The problem is, when i copy, i get something like this:

```
def decrypt():
   ...:     ...:     with open("encrypted.txt") as fr:
   ...:     ...:         code = fr.read()
   ...:     ...:         for i in [" ","\n","#"]:
   ...:     ...:             code=code.replace(i,"")
   ...:     ...: 
   ...:     ...:     ans = ""
   ...:     ...:     for i in code:
   ...:     ...:         ans+=(chr(ord(i)-20))
   ...:     ...: 
   ...:     ...:     with open("decrypted.txt","w+") as 
   ...: fw:
   ...:     ...:         fw.write(ans)
   ...:         
   ...:
```

Which makes it hard.
How do I get rid of the ...: symbols? Or copy without them?